# How to store this type of data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have data of 10 worlds (similar to the Super Mario Brothers games). Each world has 23 levels, with each level having its own data:

- Number of enemies
- Number of coins
- Number of checkpoints

I want to store this in in my Room database for Android. My plan was to create a table for all 10 worlds:

| World | Level1 | ... | Level23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [2, 50, 5] | .... | [20, 100, 2] |
| .... | ... |  |  |
| 8 | [200, 150, 4] |  | [500, 1000, 2] |

Where each array would be in the format of `\[enemies, coins, checkpoints\]`. However, `int \[\]` arrays don't seem supported in Room Database. What is the best way to store this?

I could store my data in a separate Java class and access from there. However, I have over 1k integer values and don't know if this will impact performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a TypeConverter class to convert array data to string stored in the database and convert back when you want to get that data out. Here is an example where I store bitmap data:

```
@Keep
class DataTypeConverter {

 @TypeConverter
 fun fromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
     val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
     return outputStream.toByteArray()
 }

 @TypeConverter
 fun toBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray): Bitmap {
     return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
 }
}
```